# Get Number of WeekDays Month Wise

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo DB. Can anyone help me in how to get the number of weekdays between two Given dates in month wise.

$dayOfWeek of a date will give the value of the date 1 for sunday and 7 for saturday.

But my question is how can i increment the date from start date to end date to find the number of weekdays.

Sample Data:

> db.data.insert({"startDate":ISODate('2016-01-01'), "endDate":ISODate('2016-03-31')})

```
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.data.find().pretty()
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("57c6e6a6a1e49d654caca17a"), 
        "startDate" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2016-03-31T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Now need to find the number of Weekdays between the Start Date (2016-01-01) and End Date (2016-03-31).

With output giving Jan:21,Feb:21,Mar:23.

Please suggest for an solution...